# Formula to create a Radial Gradient

Tags: c#

I need to write my own Radial Gradient generator (without using something like RadialGradientBrush).

Currently, my code looks like this:

```
public float[,] radGrad(int width, int height, float threshold) {
     float[,] grad = new float[width, height];
     float cX = width * 0.5f;
     float cY = height * 0.5f;

     for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
          for(int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
               float pixel = (Math.Max(y, cY) - Math.Min(y, cY)) / (Math.Max(x, cX) - Math.Min(x, cX));
               pixel = fLerp(pixel, 0, 255);
               grad[x, y] = pixel;
          }
      }
      return grad;
}
```

And it produces this result:
[image]

How do I go about correcting this to make it look like the expected result:
[image]

--
Edit:
Getting closer with advice from @31eee384...

```
public float[,] radGrad(int width, int height, float threshold) {
    float[,] grad = new float[width, height];
    float cX = width * 0.5f;
    float cY = height * 0.5f;

    for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
        for(int x =0; x < width; ++x) {
            float distFromCenter = distance(cX, cY, x, y);
            float pixel = (Math.Max(distFromCenter, cY)  - Math.Min(distFromCenter, cY)) / (Math.Max(distFromCenter, height) - Math.Min(distFromCenter, height));
            pixel = fLerp(pixel, 0, 255);
            grad[x, y] = pixel;
        }
    }

    return grad;
}
```

Just need to figure out why it's adding white around the edges.
[image]

Comment: since it looks like you are using winforms, why don't you use gdi+?

Comment: This is only a test program. I'm drawing the result only to get a visual of the array it is creating. I only need the numbers.

Comment: Hmm, you're dividing x by y, but it looks like you really need distance from the center. Something like `sqrt(x*x + y*y)` with some factors. Did you just randomly choose to try dividing, or is there any logic there you'd like to understand? I think this is really a math problem, not a programming problem.

Comment: I didn't just randomly choose to divide, I'm using the formula found here: https://mathteachme.wordpress.com/2014/04/22/more-on-gradients/ I'm not convinced that this is the correct way to go, that's why I'm asking for help. Also I don't why people are down-voting, I've supplied my attempt code, the current result and the desired result. Do they want me write a 42 page question or what? They're too cowardly to leave a comment and explain themselves though.

Comment: Upvoted from me - it's a solid question and something I'm trying to do now too. Looked for that mathteachme page, but it's gone now. Even Way Back Machine doesn't have it :(

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should sin!

```
public float[,] radGrad(int width, int height, float threshold) {
     float[,] grad = new float[width, height];
     int cX = width * 0.5f;
     int cY = height * 0.5f;


     for (int y = 0; y < cx; ++y) {
          for(int x = 0; x < cy; ++x) {
               float pixel = (Math.Sin(x / y));
               pixel = fLerp(pixel, 0, 255);
               grad[cx + x, cy + y] = pixel;
               grad[cx + x, cy - y] = pixel;
               grad[cx - x, cy + y] = pixel;
               grad[cx - x, cy - y] = pixel;
          }
      }
      return grad;
}
```

Far from perfect but should get you on the right path.

Comment: I appreciate it, but this creates stranger looking results than my own, when it's not trying to divide by 0 when x or y = 0